# How to plot the variable cross-section of a cylinder?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, parametric-equations

```
x = r*cos(t) + ur*cos(t)    
y = r*sin(t) + ur*sin(t)
z = zeros(length(x))
```

Cylinder length is along the `z` direction from 0 to 10.

The variable `ur` changes with each value of `z`. It represents a variable thickness of the cylinder.

I tried `plot3()` by making `z` a matrix but it creates a circle, not a cylinder.

Comment: your `z` is just zero (in fact, it is a square matrix with zeros depending on the length of `t`). So there is 3rd dimension and `plot3()` will give you just a cricle

Answer (score 1):

z = ones(1,numel(x))'*(0:10)

would do the trick to get the values to make a cylinder with athe z from 0 to 10.

Comment: Its creating circles from 0 to 10 but not cylinder

Answer (score 1):

This code may help, instead of using `pol2cart` instruction, you can use your own equations, the resultant shape depends on the range specified in `meshgrid` at beginning, also I added Rotation option, of course you can comment that to ignore that option if you do like.

```
%===========================
% Close and Clear
%===========================
clc
close all
clear all
%===========================
% making a cylinder
%===========================
[theta, r, h] = meshgrid(0:.1:6.28,0:0.1:1, 0:.2:4); 
%====================================
% transforming the coordinate system
%====================================
[x, y, z] = pol2cart(theta, r, h); 
%====================================================
% rotating the data points around x axis by 60 degree
%====================================================
P = (rotx(60) * [x(:), y(:), z(:)]')';
%P = [x(:), y(:), z(:)];
%=======================================
%=======================================
% Drawing The Cloud Points
%=======================================
figure('Name','Cylinder Point Cloud','NumberTitle','off');
scatter3(P(:, 1), P(:, 2), P(:, 3)); % plots a circles around sample points
title('Cylinder Point Cloud');
axis equal
%===============================================
```

Comment: Your code will generate a cylinder of uniform thickness but my question is related to variable radius/thickness